# What task is supposed to be created in this example?

Tags: c, resources, real-time, semaphore, vxworks

> For an ordinary binary semaphore, a
>   task attempting to synchronize to an
>   external event creates an empty
>   semaphore....A second task which
>   controls the synchronization event
>   gives the semaphore when it is no
>   longer needed.

```
#include "vxWorks.h"
#include "semLib.h"

#define T_PRIORITY 50


SEM_ID syncExampleSem;    // named semaphore object

void initialize (void)
{

    // set up FIFO queue with emtpy binary semaphore

syncSem = semBCreate (SEM_Q_FIFO, SEM_EMPTY);

    // create task1
    taskSpawn ("task1", T_PRIORITY, 0, 10000, task1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // create task2
    taskSpawn ("task2", T_PRIORITY, 0, 10000, task2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

}

void task1 (void)
{
    // stay here until semaphore becomes available
    semTake (syncExampleSem, WAIT_FOREVER);


    // do something

}



void task2 (void)
{
    // do something



    // now let task1 execute
    semGive (synExampleSem);

}
```

My question is why don't I see the first task creating the empty semaphore, as described? (It looks like it is just done "generically" in the main function?)  **"a task attempting to synchronize to an external event creates an empty semaphore".**

Also, I don't really see how the second task is "controlling" the synchronization?

Thank you.

See: Example of synchronization through binary semaphore
http://www.cross-comp.com/instr/pages/embedded/VxWorksTutorial.aspx#VxWorks%20Programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in the example.  The first line in `initialize` should be assigning to `syncExampleSem`.

The second task "controls" the synchronization because task 1 can't proceed until task 2 "gives" the semaphore.  It doesn't really matter where the semaphore is created, as long as it is guaranteed to be created before either task tries to either give or take it.

Since these particular tasks are running in parallel, it is created in `initialize` because if it was created by task 2 you run the risk of task 1 waiting on the semaphore before it exists, and vice versa if it is created by task 1 you run the risk of task 2 giving the semaphore before it exists.

Comment: I was wondering about that first line too thanks. Regarding the semaphore being created in task 1 or 2, I see the problem you described. Does this mean the wording is wrong in this example, or am I looking at it incorrectly?

Comment: The example is worded poorly compared to the code.  In my experience semaphores are almost always initialized outside of the tasks that use them, unless you have a special situation like one task being spawned from within another one.

Answer (score 1):

SemTake and SemGive are returning errors (since the semaphore does not exist).
It is valuable to check the return codes on system calls.